# Spring / Hibernate / MySQL / JPA Entity Not Saved

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to configure an application to use spring-data-jpa 1.11.13 hibernate 5.2.10 spring 4.3.11.RELEASE

The problem is that the entity is not being persisted to the MySQL datastore.

POM Dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.46</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

MySQL DDL script

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `property` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property` (
  `id` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `supplier_id` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `main_pic` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `lat` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `lng` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `sys_type` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `one_liner` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `num_bedrooms` TINYINT(127) NOT NULL,
  `num_bathrooms` TINYINT(127) NOT NULL,
  `max_occ` TINYINT(127) NOT NULL,
  `country` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `rating` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `num_raters` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `rank` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `lowest_ppn` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `max_ppn` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `avg_ppn` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `private_pool` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `pool` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `internet_access` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `air_conditioning` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `bbq` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `satellite` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `hot_tub` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `sauna` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `parking` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `instant_book` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `updated` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `supplier_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Entity (equals/hashcode/getters/setters ommitted to save characters)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="property")
public class Property {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PropertyCompositeKey id;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="url")
    private String url;
    @Column(name="main_pic")
    @NotNull
    private String mainPic;
    @Column(name="lat")
    @Min(-180)
    @Max(180)
    @NotNull
    private Double lat;
    @Column(name="lng")
    @Min(-90)
    @Max(90)
    @NotNull
    private Double lng;
    @Column(name="type")
    @NotNull
    private String externalType;
    @Column(name="name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @Column(name="description")
    @NotNull
    private String description;
    @Column(name="num_bedrooms")
    @Min(1)
    @NotNull
    private Integer numBedrooms;
    @Column(name="num_bathrooms")
    @Min(1)
    @NotNull
    private Integer numBathrooms;
    @Column(name="max_occ")
    @Min(1)
    @NotNull
    private Integer maxOcc;
    @Column(name="country")
    @Length(min=2,max=2)
    @NotNull
    private String country;
    @Column(name="rating")
    private Double rating;
    @Column(name="num_raters")
    private Integer numRaters;
    @Column(name="rank")
    private Double rank;
    @Column(name="lowest_ppn")
    @Min(1)
    private Double lowestPpn;
    @Column(name="max_ppn")
    @Min(1)
    private Double maxPpn;
    @Column(name="avg_ppn")
    @Min(1)
    private Double avgPpn;
    @Column(name="private_pool")
    private Boolean privatePool;
    @Column(name="pool")
    private Boolean pool;
    @Column(name="internet_access")
    private Boolean internetAccess;
    @Column(name="air_conditioning")
    private Boolean airConditioning;
    @Column(name="bbq")
    private Boolean bbq;
    @Column(name="satellite")
    private Boolean satellite;
    @Column(name="hot_tub")
    private Boolean hotTub;
    @Column(name="sauna")
    private Boolean sauna;
    @Column(name="parking")
    private Boolean parking;
    @Column(name="instant_book")
    private Boolean instantBook;
    @Column(name="updated")
    @Version
    private Timestamp updated;

    public void setKey(String id, String supplierId) {
        PropertyCompositeKey pck = new PropertyCompositeKey();
        pck.setId(id);
        pck.setSupplierId(supplierId);
        this.id = pck;
    }
}
```

Embeddedable - Composite Primary Key

```
@Embeddable
public class PropertyCompositeKey implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6575008230123343148L;
    @Column(name="id")
    @NotNull
    private String id;
    @Column(name="supplier_id")
    @NotNull
    private String supplierId;
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PropertyRepository extends JpaRepository<Property, PropertyCompositeKey> {

}
```

Service Interface

```
public interface PropertiesService {

    Property save(Property property);
}
```

Service Implementation

```
@Service
public class PropertyServiceImpl implements PropertiesService {

    @Autowired
    private PropertyRepository repo;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Property save(Property property) {
        Property saved =  repo.save(property);
        return saved;
    }

}
```

Spring Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("property.dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(
        value={"classpath:/properties.properties"},
        ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"property.properties"})
public class PropertySpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
       return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
    @Bean 
    public DataSource dataSource(@Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}") String driverClass,
            @Value("${jdbc.url}") String url,
            @Value("${jdbc.username}") String un,
            @Value("${jdbc.password}") String pw,
            @Value("${jdbc.minIdleConnections}") int mi,
            @Value("${jdbc.initialPoolSize}") int is) {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(un);
        ds.setPassword(pw);
        ds.setMinIdle(mi);
        ds.setInitialSize(is);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "property.entity" });
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory, DataSource ds) {
        JpaTransactionManager jtm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jtm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory.getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
        jtm.setDataSource(ds);
        return jtm;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.setProperty(
         "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
       return properties;
   }
}
```

Test case

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class,classes=PropertySpringConfig.class)
public class TestRepository {

    @Autowired
    private PropertiesService propertyRepository;

    @Test
    @Commit
    public void testRepository() {
        Property p = new Property();
        p.setKey("TEST_ID", "TEST_SUPPLIER");
        p.setAirConditioning(true);
        p.setAvgPpn(500.0);
        p.setCountry("ES");
        p.setDescription("TEST DESCRIPTION");
        p.setExternalType("TEST");
        p.setHotTub(false);
        p.setLat(12.5);
        p.setLng(45.6);
        p.setLowestPpn(150.4);
        p.setMainPic("TEST");
        p.setMaxOcc(5);
        p.setMaxPpn(777.4);
        p.setName("TEST NAME");
        p.setNumBathrooms(3);
        p.setNumBedrooms(7);
        p.setNumRaters(5);
        p.setPrivatePool(true);
        p.setRank(1.0);
        p.setRating(4.5);
        p.setUrl("TEST");
        Property s = propertyRepository.save(p);

    }
}
```

When I run the test it completes without error but the entity is not persisted.  Log out put for save:

> DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [property.service.PropertyServiceImpl.save]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
>   DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new
>   EntityManager
>   [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
>   DEBUG:
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Not
>   exposing JPA transaction
>   [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] as JDBC transaction because
>   JpaDialect [org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect@ccd1bc3]
>   does not support JDBC Connection retrieval
>   DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource
>   - Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
>   DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Found thread-bound
>   EntityManager
>   [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
>   DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Participating in
>   existing transaction
>   DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Opening JPA
>   EntityManager
>   DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Registering
>   transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
>   DEBUG:
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated
>   identifier: component[id,supplierId]{supplierId=TEST_SUPPLIER,
>   id=TEST_ID}, using strategy:
>   org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator
>   DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA
>   EntityManager
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager
>   - Initiating transaction commit
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA
>   transaction on EntityManager
>   [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
>   DEBUG:
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA
>   EntityManager
>   [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0}
>   unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] after transaction
>   DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA
>   EntityManager
>   DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener
>   - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@50f8360d testClass = TestRepository, testInstance = property.TestRepository@61a485d2,
>   testMethod = testRepository@TestRepository, testException = [null],
>   mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@2cb4c3ab
>   testClass = TestRepository, locations = '{}', classes = '{class
>   property.spring.config.PropertySpringConfig}',
>   contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}',
>   propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}',
>   contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader =
>   'org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader',
>   parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with
>   mode [null], method annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode
>   [null].
>   DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener
>   - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@50f8360d testClass = TestRepository, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null],
>   testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration =
>   [MergedContextConfiguration@2cb4c3ab testClass = TestRepository,
>   locations = '{}', classes = '{class
>   property.spring.config.PropertySpringConfig}',
>   contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}',
>   propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}',
>   contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader =
>   'org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader',
>   parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with
>   mode [null]. INFO :
>   org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext -
>   Closing
>   org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@643b1d11:
>   startup date [Sat Jun 23 12:53:04 BST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
>   INFO :
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean -
>   Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   DEBUG:
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl - HHH000031: Closing
>   DEBUG:
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadeStyles - External cascade style
>   regsitration [persist : STYLE_PERSIST] overrode base registration
>   [STYLE_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY]
>   DEBUG:
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl -
>   Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child
>   ServiceRegistries
>   DEBUG:
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl -
>   Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all
>   child ServiceRegistries

When I changed the method in the `PropertyServiceImpl` to use `saveAndFlush` method of the `JpaRepository` the test contains the following log output with error:

> ```
> DEBUG: org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl
> ```
>
> - JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
>       java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
>         at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:255)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:143)
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject.setRollbackOnly(JpaTransactionManager.java:655)
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doSetRollbackOnly(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:860)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:830)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:522)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:286)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)
>         at property.service.PropertyServiceImpl.save(PropertyServiceImpl.java:19)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.save(Unknown Source)
>         at TestRepository.testRepository(TestRepository.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

I cannot see what I have miss configured.

Can you please tell me what I can do to fix this and get the entity persisted to the datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was using the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and then using the `getNativeEntityManagerFactory()` method when initialising the `PlatformTransactionManager` bean.  The correct way to initialise the transaction manager is:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf, DataSource ds) {
    JpaTransactionManager jtm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jtm.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return jtm;
}
```

And let Spring determine the `EntityManagerFactory` to pass.

Observed the correct configuration in this article:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.13.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.java-config

Answer (score 0):

Your issue because of wrong configuration, HibernateJpaVendorAdapter is not consists in Spring context, so you have to declare it like Spring Bean, example is below:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "property.entity" });
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter());
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
    return em;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter(){
    return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have made the change that you suggest but the problem remains.